# Rvest - using a dataframe of html rather than a webpage - and extracting formatting tags

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract formatting tags from a column of HTML (and then go on to record whether each row is bold, italic, what colour etc.) I was trying to figure out whether to use regex or an HTML parser, and was pointed in the direction of rvest. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get it to parse from a column of a dataframe as opposed to going to a URL. Also, can anyone provide some basic code for extracting any formatting tags present in the HTML (or even a list of all tags/attributes, from which I can filter to only the relevant ones from a manually compiled list).

Example of the sort of HTML, from which I would need the font size, font type, font colour, background, and the fact that it is italic:

`<div align="left" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; text-indent: 0%; font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times; color: #000000; background: #FFFFFF"> These forward-looking statements are also affected by the risk factors described below in Part I, Item 1A ("Risk Factors") and those set forth from time to time in our filings with the Securities and Exchange Commission ("SEC"), which are available through our website at <i>www.exterran.com </i>and through the SEC's Electronic Data Gathering and Retrieval System ("EDGAR") at <i><u>www.sec.gov</u></i>. Important factors that could cause our actual results to differ materially from the expectations reflected in these forward-looking statements include, among other things: </div>`

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution not with `rvest`, but with the `XML`-package could be the following:

```
htmlstring <- '<div align="left" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; text-indent: 0%; font-size: 10pt; font-family: \'Times New Roman\', Times; color: #000000; background: #FFFFFF"> These forward-looking statements are also affected by the risk factors described below in Part I, Item 1A ("Risk Factors") and those set forth from time to time in our filings with the Securities and Exchange Commission ("SEC"), which are available through our website at <i>www.exterran.com </i>and through the SEC\'s Electronic Data Gathering and Retrieval System ("EDGAR") at <i><u>www.sec.gov</u></i>. Important factors that could cause our actual results to differ materially from the expectations reflected in these forward-looking statements include, among other things: </div>'

htmlstring <- XML::htmlParse(htmlstring)
```

And then you can use [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to find out what you need, e.g. italicized parts:

```
XML::getNodeSet(htmlstring, '//i')
```