# rvest - getting style attribute of any html element

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a dataframe, of which one column is html. I am trying to deduce whether each row is bold, italic, what font size etc, as I detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105483/rvest-using-a-dataframe-of-html-rather-than-a-webpage-and-extracting-formatt)

Here is some example html:

`<div align=\"justify\" style=\"font-size: 10pt; margin-top: 10pt\">\n<b>ITEM 2. PROPERTIES</b>\n</div>"`

I am now trying to approach this by taking, if present, the style attribute from each row. How do I do this? The closest I've got so far is

`html %>% html_nodes(xpath="//div[contains(@style)]")`

but it doesn't work because 1) I don't want to restrict to div only - I want the style from every row, which may or may not come from div. Also, with "contains", I can't find how to say I want anything where style is present, rather than being equal to a specific value. If possible, I'd like the style element from each HTML string, and then to parse that into things like font size and margin-top. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to restrict to div only - I want the style from every
> row, which may or may not come from div. Also, with "contains", I
> can't find how to say I want anything where style is present, rather
> than being equal to a specific value

Just use an attribute selector, for style attribute without specifying an attribute value, on the node/document node

e.g.

```
all_nodes_with_style <- html %>% html_nodes('[style]')
first_node_with_style <- html %>% html_node('[style]')
```

NA is returned where not present when accessing the actual value with

```
html_attr('style')
```

E.g.

```
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
#> Warning: package 'xml2' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(purrr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'purrr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:rvest':
#> 
#>     pluck

cases <- c('<a href="#" id="style" style="display: none;">Me</a>', '<a href="#" id="no_style" >Nope</a>')

map(cases , ~ read_html(.) %>% html_node('[style]') %>% html_attr('style'))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "display: none;"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your answer, and it works. How can I develop it further like this: I run html %>% html_node('[style]') %>% html_attr('style') and it outputs "font-size: 10pt; margin-top: 10pt". How would I narrow down to just font-size? I tried html %>% html_node('[style]') %>% html_attr('style') %>% html_attr('font-size') but doesn't work. Also, if I have a column of html, called 'html', is there something I can do to make a column of the styles? Something like mutate(style = read_html(html) %>% html_node('[style]') %>% html_attr('style'))? Thanks again.

Comment: regex and test for match based on html_attr e.g. `font-size: (.*?);`

Comment: Yes, you can mutate to add column based on outcome of regex